# How to run a program using is extension association only.

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I would like to create a program that will allow a user to select a file they wish to open using an openFileDialog and then on return, my program will open that file in whatever program is associated with that file in the registry.

Apart from searching the registry for determining the location etc of the executing program, is there an simpler way as in using Process or similar?

Comment: Just simply `Process.Start(filePath)`, have you tried?

Comment: @David Is there a reason why you unaccepted my answer? Is there something that I left out that you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Process.Start(filePath)` for this functionality. You are not required to use a path to an executable.

For example, if you write

```
 Process.Start("test.txt");
```

Windows will open `test.txt` in whatever program is currently associated with text files (e.g. notepad).